# Joule thompson effect?

Tags: electrons, ideal-gas, hydrogen, gas, inert-gases

Basic question, since $-P$d$V$ is the internal energy of work then how can an expanding gas (i.e. positive d$V$) have an increase in temperature based upon whether it is above or below the "inversion temperature"? I'm assuming it is to do with the entropy?

Comment: what do you mean by the "internal energy of work"?

Comment: @BobD I meant it is the work done by the surroundings on the system. So a negative -PdV means the internal energy of the system went down while a positive -PdV means the internal energy of the system went up. The system can then transfer the energy loss/gain between its various forms of energy

Answer (score 1):

Generally, expanding gas does not have much meaning, as you have a variance of $2$, so you need to be precise in how it is expanding. For example and isothermal expansion has zeros increase by definition, while a reversible adiabatic (isentropic) for an ideal gas exhibits a temperature decrease.

For the Thompson effect, the assumption is that the expansion is done at constant enthalpy, which is less intuitive. $dH$ is not the work done $-pdV$, but rather:
$$
dH = Vdp +TdS \\
= -pdV+TdS+d(pV)
$$
so as you guessed, there is an entropy contribution as well as one from the $pV$ term. At the end of the day, the inversion temperature is when
$$
T\alpha_V = 1
$$
with $\alpha_V$ the thermal expansion at constant pressure. Since from Maxwell's relations you can write:
$$
\alpha_V := \frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \\
 = -\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}
$$
you can view it caused by entropy variations as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It seems pdv is the work whereas pv should be constant for ideal gas at constant temperature ie d(pv)= zero for isothermal ideal gas. That would mean pdv=-vdp. I am wondering what the VdP term means as pdv is already taken as work. Does the VdP term typically just end up as heat?

Comment: This has more to do with the motivation behind enthalpy, which is a different topic. Actually, if you interpret $$dU = -pdV+TdS$$ with the first term as work and the second as heat (valid for reversible transformations), then $Vdp$ is an extra term. The motivation is that you typically use enthalpy when $dp=0$ so that this contribution vanishes.

Comment: @lpv thanks so much for your input. At the end of the day energy is conserved and a change in internal energy where the only input and output is work and heat but Q is not TdS(except for reversible processes) does still leave me confused

Answer (score 0):

In your comment to @LPZ you asked a rarely discussed but very interesting question: "Does the VdP term typically just end up as heat?" but my answer is too long for a comment.

No, it does not end up as "heat", work does not convert to heat in a reversible process. To see what happens, recall the Gibbs-Duhem equation for a fluid in a closed system but note that you cannot get that from $dU=TdS-pdV$ because if you do so then the result is $Sdt-Vdp=0$ which, in general, is obviously nonsense; just take it for an isothermal process, $dT=0$, and you can see that it also implies an isobaric process. The error is that we have ignored the chemical potential and its contribution.

In fact, for any fluid the Gibbs energy conservation equation is $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$, and then the corresponding Gibbs-Duhem equation is
$$SdT-Vdp+Nd\mu =0 \tag{1}.$$ Calculated properly, even in a closed system for which $N=\text{const; }dN=0,$ the chemical work terms stays! Since this holds for any two equilibrium states that are infinitesimally close to each other, it also must hold, per force, to finite differences between two equilibrium states, say, $\mathcal P_1$ and $\mathcal P_2$ that are connected by a reversible path along which every state is an equilibrium one:
$$\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}SdT-\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Vdp+\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Nd\mu =0 \tag{2}$$
If you also assume that the reversible path is an isothermal one, $dT=0$, and taking into account that $N=\text{const}$ you have
$$\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}SdT-\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Vdp+\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Nd\mu \\=
-\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Vdp+N\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}d\mu \tag{3}=0$$ or
$$\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}Vdp = N(\mu_2-\mu_1) \tag{4}$$

What this tells you is that during its isothermal expansion/compression of the gas the "$Vdp$" work is converted into chemical work by changing the chemical energy of the fluid.

There are two additional comments I would like to make:

1. While during this isothermal process entropy can be absorbed or
   rejected to the environment, to the "heat" source, it has no effect
   on the work besides keeping the system temperature constant.
2. The differential form of the Gibbs-Duhem equation (1) is true to any portion of the fluid body, so it could be interpreted as
   $$\Delta SdT-\Delta Vdp+\Delta Nd\mu =0 \tag{1a}.$$ where $\Delta S:S =\Delta V:V=\Delta N:N$ and you could conceive (1a) as referring to a certain piece of the thermodynamic body going through a reversible process. When interpreted that way it could also mean that a certain piece of the size of $\Delta S, \Delta V, \Delta N$ having intensive parameters $T, p, \mu$ are being added and then the same amount is removed with $T+dT, p+dp, \mu+d\mu$ from the system. Then the Gibbs-Duhem equation gains an important new interpretation that is really illuminating: the equation (1a) or its integrated form
   $$\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}\Delta S dT-\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}\Delta Vdp+\int_{\mathcal P_1}^{\mathcal P_2}\Delta Nd\mu =0 \tag{2a}$$
   expresses a universal work conservation among elementary work processes in which the system is sandwiched between two sets of sources and sinks, one source/sink pair for each of the extensive quantities. In a reversible process, work converts only to work and only work converts to work.